# Define a key on a generic

Tags: typescript

I thought I understood how to do this, but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

I want to define a function which is a typeguard; it should determine whether an input is an object which has a given key of a given type. The problem I'm having is that where I define `U` and `U extends { [K]: V }` I get the errors:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression
> whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)

> 'K' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

```js
export const hasAndIsType = <K extends PropertyKey, V extends PossibleTypes, U extends { [K]: V }>(
  key: string,
  type: PossibleTypes,
) => (x: any): x is U =>
  has(key, x) && typeof x[key] === type;
```

Is this possible?

---

#### Edit:

I had thought that this was just a syntax error, which could be fixed as:

```js
U extends { [k: K]: V }
```

But now I'm onto the error:

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or
> 'number'.ts(1023)

Which I still get if I define the type as:

```js
export const hasAndIsType = <K extends string | number, V extends PossibleTypes, U extends { [k: K]: V }>(
```

Comment: {[key: K]: any} but K has to extend string | symbol | number when used as key ... thus PropertyKey seems to be wrong?

Comment: @Estradiaz if I define K as `K extends string | number` I still get the same error

Comment: ahh my bad has to be not extends ^^ hmm still no clue how to solve this sry

Comment: You need to use a mapped type: `{[P in K]: any}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aluan commented, you need to use a mapped type: `U extends { [k in K]: V}` (instead of an indexed signature parameter `U extends { [k: V]: V }`)